# How to calculate eigen values if hamiltonian contains some constants

Tags: python, numpy

My hamiltonian is a matrix of the following form. I want to calculate eigen values from this hamiltonain. But I don't know how to deal with U and t? Should I put them 1?

```
`H=[[0 t t 0 0 0]
[t U 0 t 0 0]
[t 0 U t 0 0]
[0 t t 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]]`
```

Comment: Maybe a [`tf.Placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) can be useful here?

Comment: I want to use np.linalg.eig(L) for calculating eigenvalues

Comment: can you write the eigen vector equation without the library method?

Answer (score 0):

Sympy module provide operation on symbolic values

```
from sympy import *
U = symbols('U')
t = symbols('t') 
H = Matrix([[0, t, t, 0, 0, 0], [t, U, 0, t, 0, 0], 
              [t, 0, U, t, 0, 0], [0, t, t, 0, 0, 0], 
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

H.eigenvects() # eigenvectors
H.eigenvals() # eigenvalues
```

`eigenvals` return `{U: 1, U/2 - sqrt(U**2 + 16*t**2)/2: 1, U/2 + sqrt(U**2 + 16*t**2)/2: 1, 0: 3}` which is a dictionary of eigenvalues and their multiplicities: